# Расшифровка куки laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как можно расшифровать laravel куки обычным php? Есть APP_KEY. В laravel пока нет времени углубляться, а вот личный кабинет сделать хочется чтобы был смежный с приложением в котором есть laravel, а не отдельным.

Comment: Зачем? Их используют без шифровки и расшифровки вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
$encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class);
$decryptedResult = $encrypter->decrypt('твои куки');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я создал файл decrypt.php. Что мне нужно в него засунуть, чтобы этот скрипт заработал 
"$encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class); 
$decryptedResult = $encrypter->decrypt('твои куки');"
Если я его просто так вставляю, то выводит ошибку 500